# Are JavaFX Property objects threadsafe for multiple asynchronous writes?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, javafx, javafx-8

Is it dangerous for the standard implementations of `Property` in JavaFX to call set methods from multiple threads? I don't really care about race conditions on the client side from reading-and-then-setting operations. I want to know if the `Property` itself can be corrupted internally if multiple threads call its `set()` or `setValue()` method.

Is this code below threadsafe?

```
public class ThreadSafeProperty {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ObjectProperty<Integer> property = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(5);

        ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

        property.addListener((obs,o,n) -> System.out.println("OLD: " + o + " NEW: " + n));


        exec.execute(() -> property.set(4));
        exec.execute(() -> property.set(6));
        exec.execute(() -> property.set(11));

        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        exec.shutdown();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SimpleObjectProperty is not thread safe.

You see this in the source: javafx/beans/property/ObjectPropertyBase.set is not synchronized, or you use a tool like http://vmlens.com witch looks for you:-)

[image: vmlens report]